# Python: Installing gooey using pip error

Tags: python, cmd, installation, pip

I am trying to install Gooey for python and I keep on getting this error in cmd ... I installed the latest version of pip and am running on the latest version of python:

```
C:\Users\markj>pip install Gooey
Collecting Gooey
  Using cached Gooey-0.9.2.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\markj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ti2h9xu3\Gooey\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        version = __import__('gooey').__version__
      File "C:\Users\markj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ti2h9xu3\Gooey\gooey\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from gooey.python_bindings.gooey_decorator import Gooey
      File "C:\Users\markj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ti2h9xu3\Gooey\gooey\python_bindings\gooey_decorator.py", line 54
        except Exception, e:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\markj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ti2h9xu3\Gooey\
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running the package under python 3 which is not fully compatible with the package.

That exception means your python can't understand the syntax. In python 3 the comma (`,`) [is not allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#grammar-changes), correct syntax is:

```
except Exception as e
```

Simple test on python 3:

```
$ python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> try:
...     assert 1 + 1 == 3
... except Exception, e:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

With python 2.7.9:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> try:
...     assert 1 + 1 == 3
... except Exception, e:
...     print 'false'
... 
false
>>>
```

So, try to install your package in python2, it should be fine.

EDIT 1: 
According to [this issue](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/65) that package is compatible with python 2 only.

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the .zip file from the official website here http://chriskiehl.github.io/Gooey/ and try downloading it to see if that will work.